# Cross-account DynamoDB access

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I want to migrate data from DynamoDB from one AWS account to another. Could you please advise whether it is possible using AWS Data Pipeline? Otherwise, what are other options to do this?

I have tried migrating data within the account using Data Pipeline using HiveCopyActivity. But require more details/info how it can be done across accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Data Pipeline:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb.html

For cross account, you need to share S3 in source account to another account